# Displaying the records not present in the second table in MySQL+

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql++

```
SELECT C.COURSE_ID, TITLE, A.STUDENT_ID, COMPANY_ID, AD.ADDRESS
FROM COURSE C, STUDENT S, ADDRESS AD, ATTENDANCE A
WHERE C.COURSE_ID = AD.COURSE_ID
AND AD.ADDRESS = A.ADDRESS
AND A.STUDENT_ID = S.STUDENT_ID
AND COMPANY_ID IS NOT NULL;
```

I have got 4 tables and this query does all it needs to except that i have to include the ADDRESS not present in the Attendance table.
For example

```
ADDRESS TABLe          ATTENDANCE table
Address                  Address
  a                         a
  b                         b
  c
  d
```

So i want the end result to show:

```
COURSE ID    TITLE   STUDENT_ID   COMPANT_ID   ADDRESS
   BLA        BLA      BLA         BLA           a
   BLA        BLA      BLA         BLA           b
   BLA        BLA      BLA         BLA           c
   BLA        BLA      BLA         BLA           d
```

While the query above shows the same result but excluding c and d present in 'address' column.

Sorry if i'm not clear enough. Thank you

Comment: What table does the alias "O" represent?

Comment: ahh thats stupposed to be AD.. sorry my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your query to use an [`LEFT JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) to join the `ATTENDANCE` table it will *exclude* all records not present in it that are in the `ADDRESS` table

Comment: `INNER JOIN` will remove records that aren't linked into the other table.
`LEFT JOIN` seems slightly more appropriate for your answer?

Comment: I wanted to include not exclude. Thanks

Comment: I misread the question. A `LEFT JOIN` is exactly what should be used.